# Pymongo Celery ConfiguraionError Unknown option auto_start_request

Tags: python, mongodb, celery, pymongo

I am using decorator inside my tasks which it manages my tasks. And I am using MongoDB as celery backend.

```
@app.task(bind=True)
@my_customize_decorator
def some_task(self):
     #Do something
     return
```

My decorator and task, both of them have MongoDB connection. When i send `some_task.delay()` to worker it gives me `ConfigurationError: Unknown option auto_start_request`.

I think celery sends auto_start_request option to pymongo and pymongo couldn't resolve that. But i don't know how can i override that configuration.

Comment: see the pymongo changelog for the 3.0 version [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/changelog.html#mongoclient-changes), the auto_start_request option has been removed, check your  pymongo version inside your environnement

Comment: checked and pymongo is 3.0 already.

Answer (score 1):

It causes from celery backend options. Not from task or decorator. Celery mongodb backend default options are you can see [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/cb83434fdf90bbe5a76f1e13ddb0b684cc71d1fe/celery/backends/mongodb.py)

```
self.options.setdefault('max_pool_size', self.max_pool_size)`
self.options.setdefault('auto_start_request', False)`
```

These lines are causes ConfigurationError. After i remove these lines from
`path/to/dist-pack/celery/backends/mongodb.py` issue has been solved.